# Edge Browser Automation

Tags: automation, microsoft-edge

At work we are gradually moving much of our internal programming into web apps on the intranet.

We use MacroExpress extensively throughout the company and the external script functions let us interact with the Internet Explorer sessions by way of COM automation hooks.

We're only starting to get Edge installed but when it came up on my radar I went to look it up and found zero ActiveX or COM support in the new browser.

I've Googled around a bit but found no solutions - is there anything equivalent for the new browser?

Comment: Microsoft is moving away from ActiveX and COM support. In my opinion, Edge is lagging behind Firefox and Chrome, in terms of both, programmability and HTML interpretation. It is a a first step that happens to be somewhat backwards, that moves what was IE, into the modern era. I hope this will improve in the future.

Comment: There is neither ActiveX or COM support in Edge. Internet Explorer is still installed on Windows 10, however. We've found that as part of the initial setup of a new user profile on a machine, we set IE as the default browswer and install Acrobat Reader to handle PDF files.

Comment: Unfortunately as an organization we're pretty firmly married to this particular way of doing things so as IE, VBScript/JScript and WSH in general age out we don't have any ready alternatives.

If there's not going to be any scripting interface to anything then we're pretty boned as a dept - it'll be down to simulated mouse clicks and locking down the exact size and location of screen elements to receive them.

Comment: Because of security reasons, Microsoft removes the support for ActiveX controls in MS Edge. I suggest you to check for Web Driver. WebDriver is a remote control interface that enables introspection and control of user agents. It provides a platform- and language-neutral wire protocol as a way for out-of-process programs to remotely instruct the behavior of web browsers. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver and https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/06/14/webdriver-w3c-recommendation-feature-on-demand/#5eC2AdcwgEZeV4g8.97